# yield put trigger method in takeEvery, this can make endless loop

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

this is sagas.js file; when I run my web app, an endless loop appears, and log lots of 'getInitList' in console, why?

```
import {takeEvery, put} from 'redux-saga/effects';
import {INIT_LIST_DATA} from './actionTypes'
import "./actionTypes";
import axios from "axios";

function *getList() {
    console.log('getInitList')
    const res = yield axios.get('/todolist.json');
    const data = res.data
    yield put({
        type: INIT_LIST_DATA,
        value: data
    })
}

// generator 函数
function *mySaga() {
    console.log('mySaga')
    yield takeEvery(INIT_LIST_DATA, getList)
}

export default mySaga;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different type for actions. you are listening for same types. in `takeEvery` when sagas sees `INIT_LIST_DATA` it runs `*getList()` and then inside you dispatch `put` with same action type `INIT_LIST_DATA` then your `takeEvery` will run again

```
function *getList() {
    console.log('getInitList')
    // this logic should be inside try/catch block
    const res = yield axios.get('/todolist.json');
    const data = res.data
    yield put({
        // CHANGE type to INIT_LIST_DATA_SUCCESS
        type: INIT_LIST_DATA_SUCCESS,
        value: data
    })
}

function *mySaga() {
   console.log('mySaga')
   // CHANGE type to INIT_LIST_DATA_START
   yield takeEvery(INIT_LIST_DATA_START, getList)
  }
```

Comment: replace takeEvery with takeLatest does not work,   all endless loop!

Comment: @expl updated the answer. change the action types